# Can't retrieve data from localhost tith ajax request and php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I cannot retrieve the `<p>` elements that i echo in my php script. I'd like a solution / correction similar to mine because next to the data retrieve i have to style the `<p>` nodes with a javascript function. I'll be glad if my page doesn't refresh.

PHP:

```
<?php

 $username = "root" ;
 $database = "leaderboard" ;
 $host       = "localhost" ;

 $connection = mysql_connect ( $host, $username ) or die ( "Impossibile stabilire connessione con il database della classifica!" .mysql_error() ) ;

 mysql_select_db( $database ) or die ( "Impossibile trova il database!" .mysql_error() ) ;

 if ( mysql_select_db( $database ) ) 
 {
    $SQL = "SELECT name, point FROM records ORDER BY point LIMIT 10"
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    $i = 0 ;
    while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
        {
           echo '<p id="echo"' + $i '>' + db_field[ 'name' ] ; + '. . . . ' + db_field[ 'punti' ] + '</p>' ;
           $i = $i + 1 ;
        }
   }
   else 
   {
      print "Database NOT Found ";
   }

   mysql_close( $connection );
?>
```

Ajax request(i cannot use jQuery)

```
function leaderboard( oggetto )
{
   alert ( " PROVO A LANCIARE LA RICHIESTA PER LA CLASSIFICA " ) ;

   // Ajax sinc. 
   var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
   http_request.open( "GET" , "./PhpScript/read_from_db.php?", false ) ;
   http_request.send( null ) ;

   // Here will come the style settings later
   alert( document.getElementById( "echo0" ) ) ;

   return ;
}
```

I'll be glad to recive a solution with no refreshing page, or an alternative way to solve the problem, both without jquery because of the project specs.

Comment: And where are you looking at the responseText?

Comment: Where is your `http_request.onreadystatechange` function?

Comment: Sorry but i'm newbie with php and ajax, it was my second trial. I studied the basics yesterday and two days ago but i didn't fit them very well and those are the results. Here we have to help each other so please, show me the way to solve my problem and i'll study more, because if i could help you, i would do it. :) Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english. :)

Answer (score 0):

The quoting in your `echo` statement is wrong:

```
echo '<p id="echo"' + $i '>' + db_field[ 'name' ] ; + '. . . . ' + db_field[ 'punti' ] + '</p>' ;
```

should be:

```
echo '<p id="echo' . $i '">' . db_field[ 'name' ] ; . '. . . . ' . db_field[ 'punti' ] + '</p>' ;
```

`$i` has to be inside the quotes around the ID. And the concatenation operator in PHP is `.`, not `+`.

Comment: I studied more to solve my problem and your answer it's a bit incorrect : to concatenate strings in php you have to use " . " and not " + " . The other code it's good but not this thing. Thanks!